# php2html throws "Fatal error: listen EADDRINUSE"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, task, php2html

I have a very simple grunt task:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        php2html: {
            default: {
              files: [
                {expand: true, cwd: 'content/', src: ['*.php'], dest: 'build/content', ext: '.html' }
              ]
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php2html');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['php2html']);
};
```

When I am running it with `grunt`, I get:

```
# grunt
Running "php2html:default" (php2html) task
Processing content/cart.php...Fatal error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

What is that **Fatal error: listen EADDRINUSE** and how could I fix it? My search didn't give any sensible results unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EADDRINUSE` means that the port number which which is used internally to generate the HTML is already in use. By default `grunt-php2html` uses port 8888 on localhost. Have you tried using another port in your configuration?

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        php2html: {
            default: {
              options: {
                 port: 8181,
              }
              files: [
                {expand: true, cwd: 'content/', src: ['*.php'], dest: 'build/content', ext: '.html' }
              ]
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php2html');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['php2html']);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! Indeed had Apache from MAMP running on port 8888. Solved now ;)

Comment: Just a note. Apparently it has to be `serverPort` instead of `port` according to the source code of the plugin ;)